# C# Excel Interop - Cell text cut off on publishing

Tags: c#, excel, interop, overflow

I have an Excel sheet where the text overflows the cell and into the next one, but when using the C# Excel Interop to publish this worksheet the text is simply cut off where the cell ends. If I publish the same worksheet from the Excel application the text is not cut.

I don't want to use wrapping as I'd like the resulting PDF to remain as close to the original Excel sheet as possible. How can I prevent the text from being cut off?

Comment: Can you verify that the cell to the right of the one containing the text is empty? If it's empty then Excel will display the text as overflowing into the next cell, and that behavior is reflected in an exported PDF.

Comment: You are right. It turned out that a year and a half ago someone added a workaround that caused cells with a null value to be populated with a white space. Since the cell to the right of the cell with the overflowing text was no longer empty as it should have been the text was cut off.